# How to continue a list item after a sublist

Tags: nested-lists, asciidoc

I would like to have some descriptive text in a list item after a sublist.
How to achieve that in Asciidoc?

Here is the structure I would like to have:

- A list item of the main list

  - Then a sublist with some list item
  - Just another sublist item to give the sublist sense

  **And after the sublist some more descriptive text.**
- A subsequent item of the main list.

**What I have tried:**

Starting point:

```
* A list item of the main list
  ** Then a sublist with some list item
  ** Just another sublist item to give the sublist more sense
  *And after the sublist some more descriptive text.*
* A subsequent item of the main list.
```

- The comment `//--` ends the main list. So it is not helpful at this point.
- Stuff like multiple newlines does not help to end a sublist.

In [Orgmode](https://www.orgmode.org) the following code gives the desired layout:

```org
- A list item of the main list
  - Then a sublist with some list item
  - Just another sublist item to give the sublist more sense
  *And after the sublist some more descriptive text.*
- A subsequent item of the main list.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [attaching blocks to an ancestor list](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/lists/continuation/#attach-to-ancestor-list).

For example:

```
* A list item of the main list
+
--
** Then a sublist with some list item
** Just another sublist item to give the sublist more sense
--
+
*And after the sublist some more descriptive text.*
* A subsequent item of the main list.
```

Comment: Ah, I need to get more used to that block-thinking of ASCIIDoc! Everything is a block in ASCIIdoc. It even rhymes! Thanks!